# How to use NPM installed react component in JSX?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to use a 3rd party react component ([react-slick](https://github.com/akiran/generator-react-slick)) within my JSX and running into a problem. I'm attempting to use it very similarly to within [this](https://github.com/akiran/generator-react-slick/blob/master/app/templates/client/js/app.jsx) example by the app creator (`example1.jsx` snippet below).

Whenever I do this I get 2 warnings and an error:

```
Warning: This JSX uses a plain function. Only React components are valid in React's JSX transform.

Warning: Something is calling a React component directly. Use a factory or JSX instead. See: http://fb.me/react-legacyfactory

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__reactAutoBindMap' of null
```

I have also tried something similar as `example2.jsx`, which was a solution found in another Stack Overflow question. However, while no warnings, or errors were thrown, in this case the code did not render at all.

I have tried various methods of using `React.createFactory` (which shouldn't be used in JSX to begin with), and other finagling but with no results.

This is probably a stupid question but how the hell do I use NPM installed components in my JSX?

**`example1.jsx`**:

```
var React = require('react');
var Slider = require('react-slick');

var SingleItem = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    var settings = {
      dots: true,
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <h3> Image slider with one item at a time</h3>
        <Slider dots={true}>
          <div><img src="/img/autumn.jpg" alt=""/></div>
          <div><img src="/img/sun.jpg" alt=""/></div>
        </Slider>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var App = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div className='container'>
        <SingleItem />
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

**`example2.jsx`**:

```
var App = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div className='container'>
        {SingleItem}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: Are you using browserify or webpack?

Comment: Currently using webpack

Comment: Not sure react-slick allows to apply settings directly as you're doing with dots={true}, instead you could do <Slider {...settings} > to reference the settings object set on render.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you aren't actually referencing the slider component. You may find that your solution looks more like

```
var Slick = require('react-slick');
var Slider = Slick.Slider
```

Use the debugger to check what object you are actually being given by the require. It is also possible that you need to require a component by directly referencing one of the libraries file e.g.

```
var Slider = require('./slider.jsx');
```

Take a look at the lib or dist directory also, you can see the module.exports value for your require.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to include Slick Slider component:

```
var Slider = React.createFactory(require('react-slick'));
```